# I write media query for small screen butt its also apply on large screen how to stop it

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px), (min-width: 360px), (min-width: 375px), (min-width: 600px){
some CSS   
 }
```

Comment: What you do is making the queries for `min-width` so it will be applied for every screen with this minimal width resolutions. You can try to use `max-width` so it will be aplied only for resolutions smaller than your `max-width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please describe your problem in the description, and not only in the title.

But your problem is that you are only using min-width. So as long as the screen is MINIMUM the width you have set in your media-query, the code will be shown. And basically all screens are minimum 320px wide, so you need to add a max-width.

**EDIT:**

To describe your media query, it says:
If the screen is a screen and minimum 320px wide

OR minimum 360px wide

OR minimum 375px wide

OR minimum 600px wide

If you insert a max-width in one of those, the others will still apply.

So to create a media query that applies between 320px and 768px you can either do:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){}
```

This will also get screens below 320px, but there are basically none of those.

Or you could write:

```
@media(min-width:320px) and (max-width:768px){}
```

This will only target the screens that are minimum 320px wide and up to a maximum of 768px wide.

Comment: when i used max-width last media query apply please answer

Comment: I have edited my answer to hopefully explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing in this code

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px), (min-width: 360px), (min-width: 375px), (min-width: 600px){
some CSS   
 }
```

is that:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
some CSS   
 }
```

As above answered you need to cut this behaviour with or a max-width or overwrite the desired mediq query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
 new css
}
```

Maybe you should read some documentation about media querys and also about mobile/desktop first.